# Theorem 3.22 from Rudin

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

**Theorem 3.22** $\sum a_n$ converges if and only if for every $\varepsilon >0$ there is an integer $N$ such that $$\left|\sum_{k=n}^{m}a_k\right|\leqslant \varepsilon$$ if $m\geqslant n\geqslant N$.

Is the following statement a correct implication/corollary of the theorem?

If $\sum a_n$ converges THEN for every $\varepsilon >0$ there is an integer $N$ such that $$\left|\sum_{k=n}^{\infty}a_k\right|\leqslant \varepsilon$$ for all $ n\geqslant N$.

Comment: Your second statement is the definition of convergence of a series.

Comment: If a series converges, I know that for every $\epsilon > 0$, $\exists $ $N$ such that $n \geq N$ $\implies $ $a_n \leq \epsilon$. But I want $n \geq N$ $\implies $ $\sum_{k = n}^\infty a_k \leq \epsilon$.

Comment: No, I am not. Convergence of series imply convergence of sequences but not the other way round.

Comment: What is your definition of convergence of series then?

Comment: The answer below clarified my concern. Thanks.

Comment: I would say it is a different but related thereom.  I don't see a "closeness" enough between the two to make it easier to prove one from the other than to prove them both from scratch.  (They would both prove from scratch very similarly.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\sum a_n$ converges, then the sequence of partial sums $s_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} a_n$ converges (as a sequence). Thus there is $s \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $|s-s_n| \leq \varepsilon$ for sufficiently large $n$. But $|s - s_n| = \left|\sum_{k=n}^{\infty} a_k\right|$.